# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a simply submit form. I believe my json in mailformat is correct. Using the json in mailformat, I'm trying to check if the email that has been submitted is valid. However for some reason, react doesn't appear to be recognizing the match() method. I get an error stating "Cannot read property 'match' of undefined." My guess for a fix is something involving asynchronous programming but I am not skilled enough to come up with a fix. I'm using react hooks and state.

```
function Form({submit, setSubmit, text, setText}) {
    let emailArray = [];

    //handlers. Need for submit button and input for text
    const setTextHandler = (e) => { 
        // console.log(e.target.value)
        
        setText(e.target.value);
    };

    const setSubmitHandler = (e) => {
        let mailformat = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
        e.preventDefault();

        setSubmit(text);
        console.log(text)

        if(text.value.match(mailformat)) {
            console.log("it works")
            emailArray.push(text);
            return true
        } else if (!text.value.match(mailformat)) {
            console.log("FAIL");
            return false
        }
        
        console.log(emailArray[0])
        console.log(emailArray)
        setText("");
    }
```

Comment: A note on your "mail format": it's not 1992 anymore, valid emails these days are pretty much "does it have one and only one `@` in it? Cool, that's a valid email address"

Comment: you have to use `text.match`, as you are storing the input directly in `e.target.value`.
and instead of matching, you can use `RegExp.test` method

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last line and your setTextHandler, both setText functions are setting the text value to a string so just changing this lines would do the trick:

```
if(text.match(mailformat)) {
  // your code
} else if (!text.match(mailformat)) {
  // your code
}
```